# Starting a thread in a firework program

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, graphics

I am programing a little firework software, something where the user can choose the color, time of explosion, duration, size and form of a fuse, add other fuses and then launch them, which creates a new frame where the fuses appear at their time given and for a given duration.

I divided the problem into different classes, Etincelles for the sparks, Fusee for each fuse, and then Animation that creates the frame where the user can set up the fuses. Each of them has a paint function : peindreEtincelle(Graphics g), then peindreFusee(Graphics g) that uses peindreEtincelle, and then a paint in Animation that uses peindreFusee. Each fuse is supposed to have its own thread so that I can control when to deactivate it, and I have already tested peindreFusee and peindreEtincelle in test classes and they worked fine. As there is a thread in the class Fusee, I programed a function run() that uses peindreFusee as shown below :

the class Fusee with the run() for each thread = each fuse :

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;


public class Fusee implements Runnable {
  //ATTRIBUTES
  public int num, puissEtincelles, nbEtincelles;
  public double xf, yf, duree, tpsDepart ;
  public boolean active = true ;
  public String forme ;
  public Thread anim ;
  public Color couleur ;
  public static double DIV = 1%(Math.sqrt(2)) ;
  public LinkedList<Etincelle> liste;
  public Graphics g;

  //CONSTRUCTOR
  public Fusee(int numero){
    num = numero ;
    couleur = Color.red ;
    nbEtincelles = 1 + 8^puissEtincelles; 
    anim = new Thread(this) ; 
    liste = new LinkedList<Etincelle>() ; /
    liste.add(new Etincelle(xf,yf));  
    for (int k =1 ; k<=puissEtincelles ;k++){
        liste.add(new Etincelle(xf+10*k,yf));
        liste.add(new Etincelle(xf-10*k,yf));
        liste.add(new Etincelle(xf,yf+10*k));
        liste.add(new Etincelle(xf,yf-5*k));
        liste.add(new Etincelle(xf+10*k*DIV,yf+10*k*DIV));
        liste.add(new Etincelle(xf+10*k*DIV,yf-10*k*DIV));
        liste.add(new Etincelle(xf-10*k*DIV,yf+10*k*DIV));
        liste.add(new Etincelle(xf-10*k*DIV,yf-10*k*DIV));
    }
}

//METHODS
public void run(){
    while(active == true){
        if (tpsDepart == 0) {
          if (duree>0){ 
             duree = duree-0.01 ;
             peindreFusee(g);
          }
          else if (duree == 0){
             active = false ; 
          }
        }
        else if (tpsDepart >0){
            tpsDepart = tpsDepart - 0.01 ; 
        }
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10);//pause d'un centième seconde
      }
      catch(InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
      }
}
```

Now I want to test the animation of one fuse by setting it up manually and then starting the thread ; but only a new frame painted in black appears, no fuse. My testing class looks like this :

the class testing the animation :

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

public class TestFusee extends Frame {
//ATTRIBUTS
public Fusee fus ;
public int w,h ;

//CONSTRUCTOR
public TestFuseeAnimee() {
    this.setLocation(100, 100);
    this.setSize(1200,700);
    w = this.getSize().width ;
    h = this.getSize().height ;
    fus = new Fusee(1);
    fus.active = true ;
    fus.xf = w/2 ;
    fus.yf = h/2 ;
    fus.couleur = Color.red ;
    fus.forme = "etoile" ;
    fus.puissEtincelles = 2 ;
    fus.tpsDepart = 10 ;
    fus.duree = 20 ;
    addWindowListener(new EcouteurPourFermetureFenetre());
}

//METHOD
public void paint(Graphics g){
    w = this.getSize().width ;
    h = this.getSize().height ;
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    fus.g = g; 
    fus.anim.start(); 
}


//MAIN
public static void main(String [] abs){
    TestFuseeAnimee fen = new TestFuseeAnimee();
    fen.setVisible(true) ;
}
```

And here's an example of what peindreFusee() is actually painting (here in orange dots, the form and color are chosen by the user)

[image: Example of a fuse after painting]

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code ? it would be very helpful.

Thank you very much :)

And here are the missing classes in order to test the program :

The class Etincelle :

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class Etincelle {
//ATTRIBUTS
public Color couleur ;
public double duree, x, y ;
public String forme ;

//CONSTRUCTOR
public Etincelle(double a, double b) {
    x=a;
    y=b;
    forme = "croix";
    couleur=Color.red ;
}

//METHODES
public void peindreEtincelle(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(couleur);
    if (forme == "croix") {
        g.drawLine((int)x-5, (int)y, (int)x+5, (int)y);
        g.drawLine((int)x, (int)y-5, (int)x, (int)y+5); 
    }
    else if (forme == "point"){
        g.fillOval((int)x, (int)y, 8, 8);
    }
    else if (forme=="etoile"){
        g.drawLine((int)x-5, (int)y, (int)x+5, (int)y);
        g.drawLine((int)x, (int)y-5, (int)x, (int)y+5); 
        g.drawLine((int)x-5, (int)y-5, (int)x+5, (int)y+5);//pose les points de l'étoile, qui ici ressemble plus à un carré car plus facile à coder et peu visible (petit)
        g.drawLine((int)x-5, (int)y+5, (int)x+5, (int)y-5); 
    }
}
```

}

The class EcouteurPourFermetureFenetre :

```
import java.awt.event.*;

public void windowClosing(WindowEvent w) {
w.getWindow().dispose() ;  
System.exit(0);
```

}

}

Comment: Can you add your full code? `addWindowListener` is used for swing objects, but you aren't extending anything in your code.

Comment: what are you painting? is there an image or a drawing to be shown? plus you are starting a thread in paint() - if you understand paint() is called every time something changes on the screen - so its very bad to start shooting threads each time something moves - you need to go back and understand paint()!!

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I added a picture as en example of what peindreFusee paints ! Otherwise thank you gpasch, that might be the problem. It's not something I had done in my real code just in my testing class, I'll try to rewrite it and test it again !

Comment: *"I also edited the code and put my whole code in for cricket_007, thank you for your help !"* Tip: Add @cricket_007 (or whoever, the `@` is important) to ***notify*** the person of a new comment.

Comment: I also edited the code and put my whole code in for @cricket_007, thank you for your help ! If you could just tell me if you see anything wrong in the run() or if you think it should work when I start it from another class that would be just perfect.

Comment: If I were to test this myself, I would need the `Etincelle` and `EcouteurPourFermetureFenetre` classes. It is really hard to see what is wrong with animation code without actually running it. And thanks @AndrewThompson for the ping.

Comment: Ok I sure ! At least the means there's no obvious in the run() that I would have overseen. I added the Etincelle and EcouteurPourFermetureFenetre,  @cricket_007 I hope this helps ! And thanks a lot no matter what for taking the time !

Comment: So I can see that `Etincelle` is a "Spark" with different "patterns/forms" that it can "paint/draw", then what does the `Fusee` class do other than be a `Runnable`? I see it holds a `List<Etincelle>`, but they are all the same `forme`?

Comment: @cricket_007 : yes they are all the same form, the class Fusee just draws each spark at its correct position knowing how many sparks have to be drawn (nbEtincelles is the number of sparks, and it draws it the way that is shown in the picture I added). I wrote another class for that because I was considering making them different colors or forms later once the program fully works, and because I needed a thread for each fuse.

Comment: You don't need a thread for each to make them different forms or colors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... I think this is close to what you want (without the delay... couldn't figure that out), sorry for switching any French and English :)

[image: fireworks]

**Step 1**  - Define a Drawable interface

```
public interface Drawable {
    void drawOn(Graphics g);
}
```

**Step 2** - Define an abstract Etincelle which implements this `Drawable`

```
public abstract class Etincelle implements Drawable {

    public double x, y;
    public Color couleur;

    public Etincelle(double x, double y, Color couleur) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.couleur = couleur;
    }

    public Etincelle(double x, double y) {
        this(x, y, Color.red);
    }

    protected abstract void peindreEtincelle(Graphics g);

    @Override
    public void drawOn(Graphics g) {
        Color previous = g.getColor();

        g.setColor(couleur);
        peindreEtincelle(g);

        g.setColor(previous);
    }
}
```

**Step 3** - Define an extension of the Etincelle, here we do the Point forme.

```
public class PointEtincelle extends Etincelle {

    public static final String FORME = "POINT";
    private int radius = 8;

    public PointEtincelle(double a, double b) {
        super(a, b);
    }

    public PointEtincelle(double x, double y, Color couleur) {
        super(x, y, couleur);
    }

    @Override
    protected void peindreEtincelle(Graphics g) {
        g.fillOval((int) x - radius / 2, (int) y - radius / 2, radius, radius);
    }
}
```

And the Croix forme

```
public class CroixEtincelle extends Etincelle {

    public static final String FORME = "CROIX";

    public CroixEtincelle(double a, double b) {
        super(a, b);
    }

    public CroixEtincelle(double x, double y, Color couleur) {
        super(x, y, couleur);
    }

    @Override
    protected void peindreEtincelle(Graphics g) {
        g.drawLine((int) x - 5, (int) y, (int) x + 5, (int) y);
        g.drawLine((int) x, (int) y - 5, (int) x, (int) y + 5);
    }

}
```

I also have one for the Etoille forme, but I think you get the idea.

**Step 4** - Define a Fusee, which for all purposes here, is just a really big Etincelle, and so we will define it as such. This is probably the most complicated class, but I did some reflection magic to get the different forme from the string values of "CROIX" and "POINT", for example. This will let you add different forme later on very easily. The commented out sections "work"... you can play around with uncommenting them, but they "clear" away the old Etincelle basically by redrawing a black shape over them. I wasn't sure if the Fusee should "go away" or not, so I left them commented.

```
public class Fusee extends Etincelle {

    private static final HashMap<String, Class<? extends Etincelle>> ETINCELLE_MAP = new HashMap<String, Class<? extends Etincelle>>() {{
        put(CroixEtincelle.FORME, CroixEtincelle.class);
        put(PointEtincelle.FORME, PointEtincelle.class);
        put(EtoileEtincelle.FORME, EtoileEtincelle.class);
    }};

    //ATTRIBUTES
    public int size;
    public long duree;
    public String forme;

    //CONSTRUCTOR
    public Fusee(double x, double y, String forme, Color couleur, int size, long duree) {
        super(x, y, couleur);
        this.size = size;
        this.forme = forme;
        this.duree = duree;
    }

    private static LinkedList<Drawable> getPattern(double xf, double yf, Color couleur, String forme, int puissEtincelles) {
        LinkedList<Drawable> liste = new LinkedList<Drawable>();

        if (ETINCELLE_MAP.containsKey(forme)) {
            Class<? extends Etincelle> clz = ETINCELLE_MAP.get(forme);

            Class[] params = new Class[]{double.class, double.class, Color.class};

            try {
                Constructor ctor = clz.getConstructor(params);

                liste.add((Drawable) ctor.newInstance(xf, yf, couleur));

                for (int k = 1; k <= puissEtincelles; k++) {
                    int mult = 10 * k;
                    liste.add((Drawable) ctor.newInstance(xf + mult, yf, couleur));
                    liste.add((Drawable) ctor.newInstance(xf - mult, yf, couleur));
                    liste.add((Drawable) ctor.newInstance(xf, yf + mult, couleur));
                    liste.add((Drawable) ctor.newInstance(xf, yf - mult, couleur));
                    liste.add((Drawable) ctor.newInstance(xf + mult, yf + mult, couleur));
                    liste.add((Drawable) ctor.newInstance(xf + mult, yf - mult, couleur));
                    liste.add((Drawable) ctor.newInstance(xf - mult, yf + mult, couleur));
                    liste.add((Drawable) ctor.newInstance(xf - mult, yf - mult, couleur));
                }

            } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | InstantiationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.err.printf("Forme \"%s\" is not supported\n", forme);
        }

        return liste;
    }

    @Override
    protected void peindreEtincelle(Graphics g) {

        LinkedList<Drawable> liste;

        int mult = 10 * size;

        for (int gen = 0; gen < size; gen++) {

//            clearGraphics(g, (int) x - mult, (int) y - mult, 2 * mult, 2 * mult, Color.black);

            liste = getPattern(x, y, couleur, forme, gen);

            if (gen == 0) {
                Drawable d = liste.get(0);
                d.drawOn(g);
            } else {

                for (int i = 0; i < liste.size(); i++) {
                    Drawable d = liste.get(i);
                    if (i >= 8 * (gen - 1) + 1 && i <= 8 * gen) {
                        d.drawOn(g);
                    }
                    // else {
                    //    g.setColor(Color.black);
                    //    ((Etincelle) d).peindreEtincelle(g);
                    // }
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(duree);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

//        clearGraphics(g, (int) x - mult, (int) y - mult, 2 * mult, 2 * mult, Color.black);
    }

    private void clearGraphics(Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height, Color background) {
        Color prevColor = g.getColor();

        g.setColor(background);
        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);

        g.setColor(prevColor);
    }
}
```

**Step 5** - Define the Panel on which to draw the these `Drawables`

```
public class FuseePanel extends Panel {

    //CONSTRUCTOR
    public FuseePanel() { }

    //METHOD
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        int w = this.getSize().width;
        int h = this.getSize().height;

        Color defaultColor = g.getColor();
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        g.setColor(defaultColor);

        java.util.List<Drawable> shapes = new ArrayList<Drawable>();
        shapes.add(new PointEtincelle(40, 40));
        shapes.add(new CroixEtincelle(70, 89));

        int fuseeDuree = 100;
        shapes.add(new Fusee(234, 264, PointEtincelle.FORME, Color.blue, 8, 2*fuseeDuree));
        shapes.add(new Fusee(500, 264, CroixEtincelle.FORME, Color.yellow, 20, fuseeDuree/2));
        shapes.add(new Fusee(400, 400, EtoileEtincelle.FORME, Color.red, 8, 5*fuseeDuree));

        for (Drawable d : shapes) {
            d.drawOn(g);
        }
    }

    //MAIN
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                final Frame f = new Frame();
                f.setLocation(100, 100);
                f.add(new FuseePanel());
                f.setSize(1200, 700);

                f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                        super.windowClosing(e);
                        f.dispose();
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks pretty good @cricket_007 thanks a lot ! I'll take a closer look at it in the next few days and come back to you if I have any questions, but thank you so much for your help :)